# Nodejs connection.connect is not a function - SQL query results is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I was following a tutorial trying to connect Node.js with Mysql database .
I'm using xampp and phpmyadmin

This is the output on the terminal :

`connection.connect is not a function`

`listening on port 3000...`

`undefined`

*(I've alread run npm install mysql2)*

**Database name :** proglang

**Database table :**

[image]

and here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const app = express();


const query= async (sql)=>{
try{
    const connection =  mysql.createConnection(
{     
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'root',
    password:'',
    database : 'proglang' ,
    port: 3306
});
  connection.connect((err)=>{
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
      else{
          console.log("connected");
      }
  })
const [results, ] = await connection.execute(sql);
return results;
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err.message);
}
}
(async()=>{
    try{
        const results = await query('SELECT id, name, released_year FROM sprogramming_languages ');
        console.log(results); *for some reason this result is undefined* 
    } catch(err){
       console.log(err);
    }
}) ();

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:"welcome",
        app:"testdb"
    })
})

const port =3000;
app.listen(port,( )=>{
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}... `);
})
```

thank you so much.

Comment: as it already states connect is not a function ... the toturial you followed is outdated.

Comment: @anees not necessarily, I once had an error saying 'replace()' is not a function, just because I made a mistake in the path. And it worked when I fixed it. But for 'createConnection()' I'm not sure where the problem is

Comment: I don't know Node.js very well, but it looks to me like you're mixing `mysql2` and `mysql2/promise` syntax. You should probably consult the official documentation for the proper syntax in this case rather than relying on the tutorial.